Cannot change "Google Location Accuracy"
I have a Motorola gPower 2021 Android Phone.
Android Version: 11
Build Number: RZBS31.02-143-27-25
No further software updates available.
I am trying to change my "Google Location" Accuracy setting
I go to Settings -> Location -> Advanced (open drop down) -> "Google Location Accuracy"
This opens up a new window on my phone, with nothing but a black screen. I have let it sit for a significant amount of time and nothing ever loads. I have a solid internet connection, no connectivity issues, but nothing loads.

Could be a problem with the WebView (the embedded web browser component of Android). I have encountered similar problems some times on some of my devices. First you should check in Android developer settings what app is used as "WebView provider" On some Android versions it defaults to Chrome on other to a special WebView app.

@Robert Thank you, your comment got me headed in the right direction. I looked at the WebView app and cleared its Cache and then I was able to get to the setting.

So, to officially post an answer, here is what worked for me:
Settings -> Apps & notifications -> "See all ___ apps" -> Android System Webview -> Storage & cache -> Clear cache
